# Get two elements from a json dict into a list

Tags: python, json

I have this json file, with multiple dicts containing 3 values and 3 keys

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mælk",
        "co2": 1.25,
        "date": 15121999
    },
    {
        "name": "Piskefløde",
        "co2": 5.69,
        "date": 15071999
    },
    {
        "name": "mælk",
        "co2": 10.0,
        "date": 10101010
    },
    {
        "name": "milk",
        "co2": 745.0,
        "date": 19101919
    },
    {
        "name": "M\u00e6lk",
        "co2": 12.5,
        "date": 10101010
    },
    {
        "name": "Hytteost",
        "co2": 44.459999999999994,
        "date": 17181717
    }
]
```

Until now I can only figure out how to print a list of the "navn"
CODE:

```
def remove_prod():
    f = open("database.json",)
    f = json.load(f)
    prod_remove = []
    for dct in f:
        if "navn" in dct:  # the elements are dicts!
            prod_remove.append (dct["navn"])

    for index, item in enumerate(prod_remove, start=1):
        item_title = item.title()
        print(f'[{index}] {item_title}')
```

and this makes a list looking like this, so its just a list with the name and not date

```
[1] Mælk
[2] Piskefløde
[3] Mælk
[4] Mælk
[5] Mælk
[6] Hytteost
```

And I want it to look like this - so it prints out the name and the exact date afterwards in the same line.

```
[1] Mælk - 15121999 #and so on for the rest
[2] Piskefløde - "with the date from the json file"
[3] Mælk - "with the date from the json file"
[4] Mælk - "with the date from the json file"
[5] Mælk - "with the date from the json file"
[6] Hytteost - "with the date from the json file"
```

Hope u guys understand what I want to do, else let me know, and I will try to specify it

Comment: Please, update to mention “name” instead of “navn”. Not all of us speak a non-english language unfortunately.

Comment: it could be anything so I don't see the problem I could have written "hsjadhakdwkj" and it will be the same ?

Comment: I'd agree, it's a minor thing; however at least to me it's slightly inconvenient, as I have to read a bit further to understand that the word "navn" is associated with "name". My meaning is I wouldn't be able to make that association immediately, because the term is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 2):

something like the below

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "Mælk",
        "co2": 1.25,
        "date": 15121999
    },
    {
        "name": "Piskefløde",
        "co2": 5.69,
        "date": 15071999
    },
    {
        "name": "mælk",
        "co2": 10.0,
        "date": 10101010
    },
    {
        "name": "milk",
        "co2": 745.0,
        "date": 19101919
    },
    {
        "name": "M\u00e6lk",
        "co2": 12.5,
        "date": 10101010
    },
    {
        "name": "Hytteost",
        "co2": 44.459999999999994,
        "date": 17181717
    }
]
for idx,e in enumerate(data,1):
  print(f'[{idx}] {e["name"]} {e["date"]}')
```

output

```
[1] Mælk 15121999
[2] Piskefløde 15071999
[3] mælk 10101010
[4] milk 19101919
[5] Mælk 10101010
[6] Hytteost 17181717
```